# Do we have to upload infopath2013 form in central admin to use centrally managed data connection

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I am trying to use a dataconnection file that stored in central admin but when i am trying to publish the form it throw below arrow.

"This form template requires administrator approval. To publish the form template, 
click the File tab, click the SharePoint Server button on the Publish tab, and select the Administrator-approved option in the publishing wizard."

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your form is having Security level as Full Trust.
You can find this security level at File -> Form options-> Security and trust category

Comment: I changed the Security level to Full trust but it still throws same error while trying to publish the form.Error-"This form template requires administrator approval. To publish the form template, click the File tab, click the SharePoint Server button on the Publish tab, and select the Administrator-approved option in the publishing wizard.
"